# ASP.NET: on the server side, create PDF copy of HTML, CSS and Javascript webpage, exactly as it appears in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, pdf

Is it possible to use C# to render an ASP.NET view on the server side and save it as a PDF, preserving all the visual elements that involve CSS and Javascript, exactly as it renders in Chrome? The Javascript includes the latest versions of the standard Bootstrap and d3 libraries, as well as code using d3 to draw SVG charts. The page's CSS heavily uses Bootstrap.

I've tried a few things including IronPdf, but it completely destroys the formatting no matter what options I have tried. The only good results I've been able to get are by actually viewing the web page in Chrome, trying to print it, and saving it as a PDF that way. I'm trying to basically get exactly the same results using backend C# code to generate the PDF, without any user interaction needed. Can this be done? If it's impossible to render perfectly as a PDF I would also be open to other visual file formats that preserve the appearance of the web page.

Comment: [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) may be an option, particularly CefSharp.Offscreen - iirc there is save to PDF functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any install of chrome in headless mode and send it a command to print:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file1.pdf https://www.google.co.in/
```

I did this a couple of years ago. I created a microservice that took a URI, a test javascript, and a massage script then returned a pdf.

**Test Script:**
The test script is injected into the page and is called repeatedly until it returns true. The script should verify that components are in a properly loaded state. (This could be skipped by simply using a long delay prior to printing the pdf)

**Massage Script:**
The massage script is not required. It is injected into the page to alter the javascript or HTML prior to printing the pdf.

I used this heavily to load the entire user JOM including all Angular data stores (NGRX) since the user context was not present in the server-side Chrome instance.

**Delayed Printing:**
Since this is not a feature supported by chrome, I made an endpoint on my server that would hold a GET connection indefinitely. A script referencing the endpoint was injected into each page to be printed. When the **Test Script** returned ready, the code would cancel the script request by changing the script tag src to an empty script file that would return. This would conclude the last item that Chrome was waiting on and the documentready event would fire thus triggering the chrome print.

In this way, I was able to control Chrome printing on complex authenticated pages at my server.